# Structuring/architecting an Azure Mobile Apps Service Entity Framework Code-First and .NET APK project

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am an experienced .NET/C# developer but new to pretty much all of the technologies/libraries here including SQL/DB work.

I am developing a project with an Azure/Entity Framework .NET backend and portable .Net APK for consumption in a number of other projects. I am trying to follow recommended practices and guidelines, but it's surprisingly hard to find documentation. I find myself repeatedly feeling like I'm fighting against the system, and slowly beating out a seemingly endless succession of fires with a blunt table spoon.

I find myself wondering if the overall architecture I'm using is the fundamental problem here. I prefer to pretend I'm not merely incompetent.

## Current Structure

- DTO contracts project

  - Interfaces for the DTO classes shared between the other two projects
- Backend project

  - Implementations of the DTO interfaces + conversion to/from model classes
  - Code first database model classes
  - `TableController<SOME_DTO_CLASS>` implementations
  - `ApiController` for non-query operations
- Portable SDK library project

  - Implementations of the DTO interfaces + conversion to/from SDK classes
  - SDK exposed classes for use from other applications
  - Service class that wraps `MobileServiceClient` and `IMobileServiceTable` and exposes SDK classes

## Motivation/Implementation

#### Contract interfaces

The motivation for the DTO contract interfaces is to get as far away from magic strings / relying on member names as possible. These are interfaces rather than classes because `TableController<T>` requires implementations of `ITableData`, which is not available for use in the portable DTO contracts project.

#### Backend

The `TableController<SOME_DTO_CLASS>` classes GET methods currently refer to the current context (NOT `this.Query()`) and `.Select()` to create matching instances of the DTO classes. Lazy-loading is intact. These GET methods apply a `.Where()` with `this.User` to filter out only those entities the user has permission to access.

The Code-First model entirely derives from `EntityData`, even if the class is not going to be exposed via a `TableController<T>`. Navigation properties are used to types that are NOT exposed via their own `TableController<T>`. The fluent API is used to describe relationships.

The DTO classes expose their relation properties as the interface types rather than their concrete types because that's how interfaces work.

#### SDK

Currently this uses `IMobileServiceTable` but will likely switch over to `IMobileServiceSyncTable` at some point.

The DTO classes expose their relation properties as the interface types rather than their concrete types because that's how interfaces work.

## Current flaming spoon target

Right now I've got the SDK successfully exposing it's own SDK types pulled down from the database. `DB model -> DB DTO --> *MS Code* --> SDK DTO -> SDK exposed class` all works.

Sort of.

The DB DTO classes' properties that expose other DB DTO classes appear to be ignored in transmission despite being part of the IQueryable returned in the GET method. I cannot retrieve them using `$expand=` as apparently `The specified type member 'TestClass' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.` This still occurs if I switch from interface property types to concrete ones.

I could potentially avoid this issue by only including foreign key IDs and fetching linked entities separately in the SDK, but that seems highly inefficient and somewhat very nope.

## Get to the question you 4AM fool!

Dis gud?

More specifically (and formally) is this current project structure reasonable and likely to be sustainable? Are there any obvious flaws or oversights that will prevent this from working?

Assuming this is reasonably reasonable, what is the proper way to tackle the DTO $expand issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $expand attribute is the way to go, but unfortunately the Azure Mobile client SDK blocks this in the query string. It will be fixed in the future, but for right now your best bet is to use an attribute on the server side to add the query string on incoming requests.

For an example of this, see https://github.com/paulbatum/FieldEngineerLite/blob/master/FieldEngineerLite.Service/Helpers/ExpandPropertyAttribute.cs. The sample is for Azure Mobile Services, but that code can be easily applied to the Azure Mobile Apps server SDK.